# Access Subform SourceObject Set to Query updated with SQL - Column Order and Width?

Tags: vba, ms-access, dynamic-sql

I have an Access form with different functions users can do. They are pulling lists of data, all from 1 table.  Based on different filters or operations they want to do, I dynamically construct the SQL, use that to update the query defs of a query, and then set the subform object to that updated query.  The problem is that the one I update the subform source object to the query, I need the columns that show to be in the order of the query.

This is the code I use, at different points of use on the form, depending on if they are interacting with a combo box, entering a filter into a textbox control on the main form, and I use similar code to set the default sql/query defs on load of the form.  Why don't the columns always show in the same order as the sql that was updated to the query's definition?

```
Dim fsql As String

fsql = "SELECT table1.field1, table1.field2, table1.field3, table1.field4, table1.field5, table1.field6, table1.field7 " & _
            "FROM tblVFileImport "

If Nz(Me.cboFilterA, "") = "" Then
    fsql = fsql & "ORDER BY table1.field2, table1.field3 "
Else
    fsql = fsql & "WHERE table1.field6 = '" &Me.cboFilterA & "' "
    fsql = fsql & "ORDER BY table1.field4, table1.field5 "
    Me.cmdExtrabutton.Visible = True
End If
    
CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qrySubformSpecs").SQL = fsql
Forms!frmDoStuff.Form.frmDoStuff_SubResults.SourceObject = ""
Forms!frmDoStuff.Form.frmDoStuff_SubResults.SourceObject = "Query.qrySubformSpecs"
```

The columns get in order some times, but not consistently.

I also want to fit the columns a small as they can, fitting the contents of their respective data, if that's possible. The column fit is not as big of a deal, because the user can select the left corner and then double-click between the columns if they really need to.  The order of the columns is definitely more important here.

If anyone knows how to accomplish this, I would really love the help.  Thanks!

FWIW, the backend is SQL, so this is all coming from 1 big linked table.  The performance is quick and not an issue, but the column order is important and needing to work right.

Comment: Can't replicate the issue of column order. Setting column width requires a form as SourceObject.

Comment: Review [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52763115/7296893). Using a form to display the data fixes a lot of issues, and it contains code to autofit the column widths. I've got an adapted variant to load SQL instead of a recordset but adapting it is trivial.

Comment: Thanks, June7. I was seeing the same issue with the width issue.  Not sure what was going on with the updating of the column order to follow the updated query def.  I adjusted what we are doing on the form, so that I can use the same layout the whole time. I think I'm ok now.  I could do an actual subform, but I didn't want to have to manage the form object, the field controls and datasheet labels etc. Just not enough time.