# Update datasheet form to show all fields from crosstab query

Tags: ms-access

Is it possible to add a field to a form that's displaying in *Datasheet* view?
Looking at the design of the form a control is added for each field and then displayed as a Datasheet, so I'm thinking it may not be possible at run-time.

As an example I have a small database that can be built using this code:

```
Sub CreateDB()

    DoCmd.RunSQL "CREATE TABLE EmployeeDetail " & _
                 "(ID AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, " & _
                 "Forename TEXT(255), " & _
                 "Surname Text(255))"
                 
                 
    DoCmd.RunSQL "CREATE TABLE HourlyRateTypes " & _
                 "(ID AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, " & _
                 "RateType TEXT(255),SortOrder INTEGER)"
                 
    DoCmd.RunSQL "CREATE TABLE    EmployeeHourlyRates " & _
                 "(ID AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, " & _
                 "EmployeeID INTEGER CONSTRAINT FK_Employee REFERENCES EmployeeDetail (ID), " & _
                 "RateID INTEGER  CONSTRAINT FK_Rate REFERENCES HourlyRateTypes (ID), " & _
                 "RateAmount CURRENCY)"
                 
                 
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO EmployeeDetail (Forename, Surname) VALUES ('Some', 'Body')"
    
    DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO HourlyRateTypes (RateType, SortOrder) " & _
                 "SELECT * FROM (" & _
                 "SELECT 'Normal' as RateType, 1 AS SortOrder FROM MSysACEs " & _
                 "UNION SELECT 'Time Half', 2 FROM MSysACEs)"
                 
    DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO EmployeeHourlyRates (EmployeeID, RateID, RateAmount) " & _
                 "SELECT * FROM (" & _
                 "SELECT 1 AS EmployeeID, 1 AS RateID, 15.67 AS RateAmount FROM MSysACEs " & _
                 "UNION SELECT 1,2,20 FROM MSysACEs)"
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    
    
End Sub
```

This SQL creates the view I'm after.
The SortOrder column ensures the fields are in the correct order as long as I'm not using more than 9 fields.

```
TRANSFORM           Sum(EmployeeHourlyRates.RateAmount) AS SumOfRateAmount
SELECT              Forename, Surname
FROM                HourlyRateTypes INNER JOIN 
                        (EmployeeDetail INNER JOIN EmployeeHourlyRates ON EmployeeDetail.ID = EmployeeHourlyRates.EmployeeID) 
                            ON HourlyRateTypes.ID = EmployeeHourlyRates.RateID
GROUP BY            Forename, Surname
PIVOT               [SortOrder] & ":" & [RateType]
```

I then display this as a datasheet in a form:
[image]

Now, if I add a new record to `HourlyRateTypes` - **Double Time** with a "SortOrder" of **3**.
And a new record to `EmployeeHourlyRates` - EmployeeID: **1**, RateID: **3**, RateAmount **£40**

[image]

My query will show the new field:
[image]

My form however, doesn't update to include this new field as the wizard just built it with the fields in the query at the time.

Does anybody know of a way of displaying all the fields shown in the cross-tab query?
Would a listbox be better so I just have to change the number and widths of the columns (through VBA).
All ideas gladly accepted.

Comment: You can use the actual query as subform, by setting the subform control `.SourceObject` to `Query.MyCrosstabQuery`. If you need an actual form for events etc., something like this could perhaps be adapted: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52763115/3820271

Comment: Thanks @Andre, the link looks like it's what I need.  Funny that it's an answer I've already seen and upvoted.  I'd answered the question as well.  Completely forgot about it. :)

Comment: Yup, I've used that approach previously for crosstab queries, you should be able to use it with 0 adaptation, just call DisplayRS on a recordset of the crosstab results. I have noticed some funky behavior when filtering/sorting crosstab results as noted there, see the adaptation to solve that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48886278/7296893). @Andre the .SourceObject trick unfortunately refuses to work on subqueries with a variable amount of columns (crosstabs without an IN)