# How to bind a report to a dataset/datatable via VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm using the term dataset/datatable as I'm coming from .NET.
Basically, I have a query where I need to 'refactor' the output to the correct format. In .NET I'd create a dataset and loop thru all the records. I'd have a table in the memory, which I'd bind to the report. Is the recordset the right object to do it?

This is what I've got, but not sure if it's the right way:

```
Dim db As Database 
Dim rs As Recordset 
Dim qdfParmQry As QueryDef

Set db = CurrentDb()
Set qdfParmQry = db.QueryDefs("qryRptAllPositions")
qdfParmQry("ID") = '[Forms]![KO]![ID] 

Set rs = qdfParmQry.OpenRecordset()
 
Do While Not rs.EOF
    Debug.Print rs![POSNO]
    ' custom logic
rs.MoveNext

Loop

Me.RecordSource = rs 'ERROR type mismatch

Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
```

Comment: What the specific issue you are having? Is the question "is this the right way" or how to resolve the type mismatch?

Comment: First of all, I want to do it the "right way". And the issue is how to bind my recordset to the recordsource

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't do this for reports.

You want to do all modification in the query itself (and can, of course, create a query based on another query, and use VBA in queries used for reports).

You can also do modification in the report itself by binding columns to functions that take the query content (e.g. `=FormatMyColumn(MyColumn)`)).

You can also consider writing the content to somewhere (to a temporary table, Excel file, or other ODBC data source you can query using queries, possibly an in-memory one)

For forms, this is possible, but you set the *recordset*, not the *recordsource*:

```
Set Me.Recordset = rs
```

Note the `Set` keyword, since a recordset is an object.

Setting the recordset will automatically change the record source to the recordsets text, and Access can and will requery based on the record source (when sorting/filtering/refreshing/etc.) which may cause problems

You generally want to avoid setting the recordset whenever possible. There are situations when it may be hard, for example with parameterized passthrough queries or unsupported recordset types, but setting the recordset opens the door to [all kinds of problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48886278/7296893).

Comment: Thank you, Erik. But I get a runtime error "this feature is only available in an ADP".

Comment: @Nearshore Ah, a report, then it's not possible unfortunately. I've edited the answer.