# MS Access - How to properly use Pass-Through queries as source for form

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

In my MS Access FrontEnd connected to an SQL Server, I'm using a combination of pass-through queries and "normal" ODBC connection via file-DSN (for "easy bound forms") for my forms.
Within VBA functions and Subs I use some ADO connections to directly change data in the tables.

I need pass-through queries for some forms as I need to use `DISTINCT` keywords on tabels with `MEMO / NVARCHAR(max)` fields.

Currently I'm using the pass-through query to get the data into my forms like that:

```vba
strSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT tbl_Changes.Change_Nr, Title, Comment FROM [tbl_Changes] inner JOIN tbl_Parts ON tbl_Changes.Change_Nr = tbl_Parts.Change_Nr " & _
    "WHERE '" & strProject & "' IN (" & strAllProjects & ") " & _
    "ORDER BY tbl_Changes.Change_Nr DESC"

Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef, rst As DAO.Recordset
Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("")
qdf.Connect = Application.TempVars("tempvar_StrCnxn")
qdf.sql = strSQL
qdf.ReturnsRecords = True
'Debug.Print strSQL
Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset
Set Forms![frm_ChangePartsOverview].Recordset = rst
Forms![frm_ChangePartsOverview].Requery
'No rst.Close to have the data still in the Form!
Set qdf = Nothing
```

But I think this is not the correct approach to do it, or is it?

Comment: Why do you think it's not the correct approach? And what's 'correct' here? Sure, you can bind to an ADODB recordset as well, but this should work just fine. Beware of sorts/filters if Access cannot parse the SQL, though, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48886278/7296893)

Comment: I think this may not be correct as I have this in the "open" event. So everytime this gets opened, it re-do's the connection. And I never set "rst.Close" here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your concerns in the comments:

`rst.Close` is redundant in VBA, the garbage collector takes care of closing recordsets and only in very rare cases will you need to close them manually.

In theory, you could have a `Form_Close` or `Form_Unload` handler to close the recordset, but there's no need.

DAO also caches database connections and reuses them when needed (something which some users use to keep passwords out of connection strings, since if a connection is established with the password, it's cached and can be used in linked tables without specifying it again, but this also causes bugs, for example with `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON` which `DoCmd.TransferDatabase` uses).

That said, there are alternate approaches, but they all come with advantages and disadvantages.